# How to calculate density across column in data frame grouped by another column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, kernel-density

I am trying to use the dplyr package and group_map to execute a density function on a column in my data frame. The frame contains ~ 4 million entries. The group map returns a list of identical values, instead of unique values for each group specified by a grouping variable.

I have tried using `gapply()` already but the size of my data frame is too large for that to run efficiently. I have also tried group_modify, but I am returned an error message stating "the result of .f should be a data frame."

```
mydensity <- df %>%
               group_by(ID_group) %>%
               group_map(~density(df$avgvalues))

densitylist <- as.data.frame(mydensity)
```

I expected this to return me a data frame of unique density values for each ID_group, but instead, I received this error message:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"density"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: what you are receiving is the the fact that `density` does not return `x` and `y`, but returns an object of class `"density"`. Try for example to run `unclass(density(rnorm(100)))`. This is the underlying structure of the output from density. How should this be converted to a data frame?

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification Oliver. What I am trying to find is a central value for density per group, so I can obtain a measure of grouped central tendency. Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: What do you describe as a "central tendency" measure? Most would likely think of the mean or median of the distribution when hearing of central tendency, so i am not sure I'm picking up correctly on the end goal.